# read query performance effects of normalizing database schema

Tags: database, schema

I have a database designed. One of the tables will grow to have over 100 million rows. It is possible to normalize the schema to move 7 of the 17 fields into another table and use a foreign key to point to the other table which will be a smaller table under 500 thousand rows and will  but still it will not affect the number of rows in my big table.
Does normalization in this case speed up or slow down read queries on the big table?

My educated guess is that because you'd have to do an extra join on the other table to get all the information, normalization will slow down the read queries.